# How to use map with a function that needs more arguments

Tags: scheme, racket, map-function, partial-application

I am trying to use map with `(string-split "a,b,c" ",")` to split strings in a list.

```
(string-split "a,b,c" ",")
'("a" "b" "c")
```

Following works if string-split is used without ",":

```
(define sl (list "a b c" "d e f" "x y z"))
(map string-split sl)
'(("a" "b" "c") ("d" "e" "f") ("x" "y" "z"))
```

But following does not split strings in the list around ",":

```
(define sl2 (list "a,b,c" "d,e,f" "x,y,z"))
(map (string-split . ",") sl2)
'(("a,b,c") ("d,e,f") ("x,y,z"))
```

How can I use map with functions that need additional arguments?

Comment: `(map (lambda (x) (string-split x ",")) lst)`

Comment: Simplest! You should have entered it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#lang racket

(define samples (list "a,b,c" "d,e,f" "x,y,z"))

;;; Option 1: Define a helper

(define (string-split-at-comma s)
  (string-split s ","))

(map string-split-at-comma samples)

;;; Option 2: Use an anonymous function

(map (λ (sample) (string-split sample ",")) samples)

;;; Option 3: Use curry

(map (curryr string-split ",") samples)
```

Here `(curryr string-split ",")` is `string-split` where the last argument
is always `","`.

Comment: Option 4: use `cut` from `srfi/26`.

Comment: Heard curryr for the first time!

Comment: Option 5: require [`fancy-app`](https://github.com/samth/fancy-app), use `(map (string-split _ ",") samples)`

Answer (score 1):

`map` applies a procedure of `n` arguments to the elements of `n` lists. If you wish to use a procedure that takes other arguments, you need to define a new procedure, which may be anonymous, to call your original procedure with the required arguments. In your case, this would be

```
(map (lambda (x) (string-split x ",")) lst)
```

as @leppie already pointed out.